# Add new block/template to customer account edit page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, customer-account

I'm trying to add one new template to customer account edit page using code below in my layout file

```
<customer_account_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit">
        <block type="redbox/customer" name="linkedin_profile" template="redboxDigital_linkedin.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

I want to include my template content above change password & `Save` button. How I can do that? I know I can over-write edit.phtml and add my code there but I don't prefer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1** Add bellow code in your module layout file

> app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\your_layout_file.xml

OR

> app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_edit translate="label">
        <reference name="customer_edit">
            <block type="redbox/customer" name="linkedin_profile" as="linkedin_profile" template="redbox/linkedin.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
</layout>
```

**Step : 2** add bellow child block in file

> app\design\frontend\your_packge\your_theme\template\customer\form\edit.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('linkedin_profile');?>
```

Comment: That helps. Isn't it possible to inject my template without modifying `customer\form\edit.phtml` at all ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add your template file without modifying `customer\form\edit.phtml`. You have to use `<update handle="customer_account_edit" />` in your layout file by specifying `after="" or before="" for your template`. you need to give alias in customer.xml file for that block.

Thanks